# Why I can't change destination link on plusone button?

Tags: google-plus

My code :

```
<script src="http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<g:plusone id="googleModuloContentButton" href="http://www.mywebsite.com/?IDL=1" size="medium"></g:plusone>
```

It create the Google+ badge. But after if on a click handler I do :

```
gapi.plusone.render('googleModuloContentButton', {
    href: "http://www.mywebsite.com/?IDL=2"
});
```

the destination link for the +1 doesnt change...still the one setted on the first rendering. Why? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have automatic rendering turned on. Changing the script line to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
  {parsetags: 'explicit'}
</script>
```

Currently your button has already been told to render. Adding the parameters above should allow your code to work.

You might also consider if setting the href this way the best method as opposed to using canonical links or prepopulating the href. What is your use case?